# Download Manager Network Failure Issue

Tags: java, inputstream, skip

I am making a download utility in java which will download files from the ftp server. 
I am using URLConnection class to establish connection and inputstream as the stream object. 
The problem that i am facing is in the network failure scenario i.e 
while downloading a particular file if the connectivity is lost and after the connectivity is restored i want it to resume downloading from where it had stopped previously.

To achieve this i have done the foll :-

/*Here,I am trying to skip the number of bytes downloaded so far so as to get the pointer in stream from where it should resume downloading.The skip() method may not necessarily skip the number of bytes given as a parameter and hence the while loop. 
*/

```
while(totalByteSkipped!=downloaded) 
{ 
      bytesSkipped = stream.skip(downloaded-totalByteSkipped); 

      totalByteSkipped = totalByteSkipped+bytesSkipped; 
}
```

But this approach of manually skipping so many bytes is very slow and affects the overall time of download, hence in such a case i need a mechanism to get the pointer in the stream at the point where it had stopped downloading.

Hoping to get an alternative approach on the same. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement [FPT restart](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/64.htm) in order to resume downloads. If your server supports it, then you can tell it the offset in the file.

Is there any reason why you are not using an already existent FTP Client? [Commons Net FTP Client](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/index.html) supports restart.

Comment: Hi Vlad,
Thanx for ur reply.
I was using FtpClient from the sun.net.ftp package.Wasn't aware of the FTPClient class from apache.Will definitely try and see if it can help me with resolve my problem.
Thanx again :-)

Comment: @Shabeena: Then use http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/net/ftp/FtpClient.html#setRestartOffset%28long%29

Comment: FtpClient does not have any convenience method for the restart offset but FTPClient from apache does.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice it was the OpenJDK version I linked to. Then I guess youre better off with the Commons client.

Comment: As suggested, I have used FTPClient and FTPFile classes from the Commons client API but I am facing another problem.I am using setRestartOffset() method of the FTPClient to set the offset to resume download in case of manual pause and network failure.
Though I have managed to set the offset correctly in case of pause, the offset in case of network failure is some how not being set correctly leading to file corruption.

Comment: Here  is a snippet of the offset logic used:

if(paused)
{
    client.setRestartOffset(downloaded);
}
else if(networkFailure)
{
          client.setRestartOffset(downloaded);
          stream = client.retrieveFileStream(getFileName(url));
}
else
{
          stream = client.retrieveFileStream(getFileName(url));
    //normal flow
}
Any suggestions on the same will be appreciated.

Comment: The offset is set correctly, the `downloaded` value is probably wrong.

Comment: But 'downloaded' is only incremented after the bytes are written to the file.In such a case,I dont understand how can the 'downloaded' value be incorrect.

Comment: Usually the restart offset must be set just before the file transfer command. On network failure try: `fileName = getFileName(url); client.setRestartOffset(downloaded); stream = client.retrieveFileStream(fileName);` to make sure you're not running any ftp commands between restart offset and file transfer.

Comment: This din make a difference either!
Tried debugging and came to a conclusion that after executing the above statements in the sequence given , the offset is finally set to 0 and not to downloaded.

Comment: One more idea: is the client re-connected when you call `retrieveFileStream()` after a network failure or it reconnects in the background? Did you try to do some TCP monitoring to see exactly what's going on between the client and server?

Comment: Well no idea about this, dunno hw wud i monitor TCP!
Tried another alternative..
client.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
client.setRestartOffset(downloaded);
This set the offset correctly but still leads to file corruption.

Answer (score 0):

skip() wont work for you because it just downloads all the data and then discards it. The server is not informed that these bits are discarded, they are discarded at the client.

You are looking at the wrong end. Check if the FTP protocol (or whatever you use) allows for this behavior and which instructions you must send to use it. Otherwise they will just keep in sending you all of the data from the beginning, even if you do not want it.